# Cron tab not running javascript that reloads page

Tags: javascript, php, cron

I have a php file that send emails to our clients who are expecting it and to ease the load on the server and to eliminate it looking like a spam server we reduce the flow to 40 emails every 20 seconds. This is done by using javascript to rerun the page every 20 seconds. The page itself reads from a data base and gets the next 40 email addresses, sends them, and then recycles until all are sent. Then the email list is reloaded from a duplicate table for the next cycle three weeks out.

Here is the javascript code that seems to not run when initiated by a cron job

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout("location.href = \'PT_enrollment.php?sendDate='.$sendDate.'\'",20000); // milliseconds, so 10 seconds = 10000ms
            </script>
```

When I run this from my browser it does run correctly so I guess it is in the Cron Job functionality.

What am I missing? Is there a setting or parameter I need to set in the crontab or on the server so it runs correctly?

Comment: Why doesn't the cron tab just pull directly from the database?

Comment: The cron job is run by the server, not by a browser. The server will not execute javascript generated by your PHP code, it will simply render it. Since the output is normally not sent to a browser (unless you actually open the cron file in a browser yourself), your javascript code is effectively ignored.

Comment: Thanks rickdenhaan that answers the why now I just need to know how to make it loop every 20 seconds in php. I have a list of 3000+ emails I process and this way it takes about 25 mins which is perfect now to the php side of things thanks resubmit this as an answer and I will accept it as correct so you get credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have your PHP process sleep for those 20 seconds:

```
$emails = // retrieve all emails from database
$done = 0;

foreach ($emails as $email) {
    // send email to $email

    $done++;
    if ($done % 40 == 0) { // every 40 emails
        sleep(20); // wait 20 seconds
    }
}
```

Ordinarily, cron jobs are run server-side via php-cli, which by default doesn't have a timeout. Some hosting providers run cron jobs by actually retrieving a URL via wget or curl, in which case you do have to account for a possible timeout. In that case, you can add `set_time_limit(0);` to your script to work around that.

Comment: thanks I modifed my code to incorporate the delay in the sleep function instead of javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know how you are running This .. The server will not run JavaScript
if you added your JavaScript to file test.php 
you can run something like

```
file_get_contents('https://yourdomain.com/test.php');
```

This will hit the file like you run on browser

or rewrite your Task on PHP language like

```
$url = 'https://yourdomain.com/PT_enrollment.php?sendDate='.$sendDate;
file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: the issue is I need to repeat this process EVERY 20 seconds. It is sending email to over 3000 people so I break it into groups of 40 every 20 seconds so it will loop 75 times. it takes about 5 seconds to run through 40 then waits for 15 then repeats). The bad way would be to put it in a loop that continuously iterates but only processes the specific routines if the time is 20 seconds out the reset the time holder but this would really tax the server